# How to get the right value in tableviewer?

Tags: java, jface, tableviewer

I created tableviewer ( jface ).

All the columns are editable ( using EditingSupport )

I want to save the changes in the table.

I Added a button of save.

The issue that I tried change the value in the cell ( the focus is still on the cell ) I press save and I want to read the value that changed.The issue that I always see the old value and not the new value.

If I changed the focus of the cell then it is working.

Do I need to add event for the editing in the cell ?

This is my code

//logic for the save button

```
      saveButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {

        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {


                     TableItem item = this.getTable().getItem(selectionIndex);
```

//The gridViewer Class

```
   public class MyGridViewer extends TableViewer {
     public MyGridViewer (Composite parent) {
    super(parent, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.BORDER);

    final Table table = this.getTable();
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);
    table.setLinesVisible(true);

    this.setContentProvider(new MyModelProvider());

}
      }

 @Override
protected void inputChanged(Object input, Object oldInput) {

    removeColumn();



        tableCol = new TableViewerColumn(this, SWT.NONE);
        column = tableCol.getColumn();
        column.setText(dataColumnHeader.getName());
        column.setWidth(100);
        column.setResizable(true);
        column.setMoveable(true);
        tableCol.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {
            @Override
            public String getText(Object element) {
                DataRow r = (DataRow) element;
                DataCell c = r.getDataCellByName(dataColumnHeader.getName());
                if (c != null && c.getValue() != null) {
                    return c.getValue().toString();
                }
                return null;
            }
        });


    editingSupport = new StringCellEditingSupport(this, dataColumnHeader);
tableCol.setEditingSupport(editingSupport);
    super.inputChanged(input, oldInput);

}
```

//The edit cell Class

```
   public class StringCellEditingSupport extends EditingSupport {
private final TableViewer tableViewer;
private final DataColumnHeader column;
private final StringCellEditor cellEditor;

   public StringCellEditingSupport(TableViewer viewer, DataColumnHeader dataColumnHeader) {
    super(viewer);
    this.tableViewer = viewer;
    this.cellEditor = new StringCellEditor(tableViewer.getTable(), SWT.BORDER);

        this.column =   dataColumnHeader;


}

@Override
protected StringCellEditor getCellEditor(Object element) {
    return cellEditor;
}

@Override
protected boolean canEdit(Object element) {
    return true;
}

@Override
protected Object getValue(Object element) {
    if(element instanceof DataRow) {
        DataRow dataRow = (DataRow) element;
        DataCell cell = dataRow.getDataCellByName(this.column.getName());
        return cell.getValue();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void setValue(Object element, Object value) {
    if (element instanceof DataRow && value instanceof String) {
        DataRow dataRow = (DataRow) element;
        DataCell cell = dataRow.getDataCellByName(this.column.getName());
        cell.setValue(value);
        tableViewer.update(element, null);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: May be you cell is not receiving focus.lost event, when you press save button?

Comment: I press on the cell insert data and then press on the save. the cell is still focus

Comment: How I can call to focus out of the cell ?

Comment: to get focus of the cell I press link on the cell

Comment: Is your Save button located in the same cell, your are trying to edit?

Comment: The save button is not located in the cell. It is a toolbar of the table.It is located above the table

Comment: Ok, what is StringCellEditor? You own CellEditor implementation? Are you sure it is correct? Why aren't you using jface.TextCellEditor

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45916/discussion-between-user1365697-and-alexander-gavrilov)